# Excel Will Not sort

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to sort a list of movies and two of the rows will not sort with the rest of the rest. They remain at the top no matter what. I have checked, for blanks before the title, checked formatting, tried unfreezing them, checked for filters, copied them into word and back into excel, deleted them and entered them entirely anew and as soon as I sort the list they go right back to the top. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be certain without an actual spreadsheet to look at. A couple of thoughts come to mind, given that you seen to have checked thhat the actual content should sort properly.

(1) Headers -  the Excel sort option let you choose whether or not the data includes header rows that are left unsorted at thr top.

(2) Formulas - if the cells you are sorting are formulas making references to a range of other cells then things may not work as you expect

To go beyond that I think we need to see the actual lists/sheets

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I tried both of those...

Answer (score 0):

When you tried the last option ("entered them entirely anew"), did you copy / paste them from a source or type them in?

If you copied / pasted them from another source, can you try typing them in?

If you entered them without copying from another source, I would recommend copying your data and pasting it into a new sheet/workbook as "text only" and without any formatting or formulas.  Once you do that, try sorting before applying any formatting, etc. Does it work correctly then?

Comment: I tried both the copy/paste method as well as entering them from fresh in a different cell and when I sort the new cell it goes right to the top.

Comment: What about copying the data from the excel sheet into a new workbook as "text only" (possibly going through Notepad to do so)?  Did sorting work in that case?  If not, inspect your text using a hex editor - maybe one of the characters is unexpected.